# How to Split Audio Tracks from ISO file

Tags: mount, iso, audio-cd

I have an ISO file that was created out of an audio CD. I received this ISO from another computer and I don't have a CD burner.

I'd like to split the audio tracks in the ISO with a program such as [`abcde`](https://abcde.einval.com) or using a more low level program such as [`cdparanoia`](http://www.xiph.org/paranoia/). I've tried to mount the ISO but I saw this directory layout:

```
/media/doron/iso
├── 2C_AUDIO
│   ├── 2C_AREA1.TOC
│   ├── 2C_AREA2.TOC
│   ├── 2C_TAREA.2CH
│   ├── TRACK001.2CH
│   ├── TRACK002.2CH
│   ├── TRACK003.2CH
│   ├── TRACK004.2CH
│   ├── TRACK005.2CH
│   ├── TRACK006.2CH
│   ├── TRACK007.2CH
│   ├── TRACK008.2CH
│   ├── TRACK009.2CH
│   ├── TRACK010.2CH
│   ├── TRACK011.2CH
│   ├── TRACK012.2CH
│   ├── TRACK013.2CH
│   └── TRACK014.2CH
├── MASTER1.TOC
├── MASTER2.TOC
├── MASTER3.TOC
└── SRM0.LST

1 directory, 21 files
```

All search results I've hit with the internet gave solutions for the reverse operation.

I know I can burn the ISO to a real CD and then read it with `abcde` but I don't have access to a CD burner/reader.

Comment: Can you try mounting the ISO as a loopback device? https://askubuntu.com/a/193632/612676

Comment: Try converting those `*.2ch` files with `ffmpeg -i /path/to/trackN.2ch trackN.flac`; if that works, then you could also split them with the `-ss` and `-t` options of `ffmpeg`. If it doesn't, then please post some details about their format eg. `hd -n32 trackN.2ch` (are they [DSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Stream_Digital)?)

Comment: I get `Invalid data found when processing input` when running the `ffmpeg` command. I don't have a `hd` command available, I use Arch Linux and I couldn't find such a command in the official repositories. When running `file TRACK001.2CH` I get only `data`.

Comment: From memory, you can't create an iso file containing multiple tracks.  A single iso represents a single track.  A link here seems to confirm that: https://club.myce.com/t/newbie-help-how-do-i-make-an-iso-of-an-audio-cd-it-doesnt-seem-to-work/122480

Comment: @DoronBehar `hd` is the same as `hexdump -C`

Comment: It is supposed to be DSD, `hexdump -C -n32 TRACK001.2CH` gives me:

 00000000  44 18 18 97 e0 00 02 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |D...............|
 00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
 00000020

Answer (score -1):

Mount the iso as loop, for that first of all enable the loop module in you system with:

```
modprobe loop
```

After that you would have to mount your iso as loop, using this sintax:

*mount -o loop isoname.iso mountpoint*

**Example:**

```
mount -o loop isoname.iso /mnt
```

You will notify that the iso content is read-only, so in case of wanting to have full access to the content, the best would be to copy it outside from the mountpoint with **rsync**.

**Example:**

```
rsync -a -H --exclude=TRANS.TBL /mnt /new_mount_point
```

Comment: The OP has already successfully mounted the ISO.  This will *necessarily* have been done by using a loop-back.